# Why is this item giver script not working?

Tags: roblox

So, I'm trying to code an LUA script in Roblox Studio that is supposed to give you a tool I named "Item" with ClickDetector if you have enough money. Here's the script:

```
local ToolNames = {"Item"}
local Storage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local itemprice = 50


local Part = script.Parent
local ClickDetector = Part:WaitForChild("ClickDetector")

ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)
    if Player and Player.Character then
        if game.Player:FindFirstChild(ClickDetector.Parent.Name).leaderstats["Cash"].Value >= itemprice then
            game.Player:FindFirstChild(ClickDetector.Parent.Name).leaderstats["Cash"].Value = game.Player:FindFirstChild(ClickDetector.Parent.Name).leaderstats["Cash"].Value - itemprice
        end
        local Backpack = Player:WaitForChild("Backpack")
        for i = 1, #ToolNames do
            local Tool = Storage:FindFirstChild(ToolNames[i])
            if Tool then
                Tool:clone().Parent = Backpack
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: I don't know much about Roblox, but `.gitignore` seems a really weird name for a script.

Comment: Oh, ignore that. It is just the link to see the script, but I'll change the post.

Comment: "not working" is never a good way to describe an issue. You've told us what you expect, which is a good thing (), you just need to tell us what you get instead.